# Firebase Database Update creating duplicate node

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a users object, in that I am trying to update a specific node(status) by using the firebase update(payload) method. But when I try to do that, instead of updating the value in the parent node, it creates a new child node(duplicate node) with the value being updated there.

```
let firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let uniqueID = "OEHCrSnKFrd87JDivvA0sLMnj8u1"
firebaseApp.database()ref("users/" + uniqueID).update({
  status: false
})
```

[Duplicate node image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfgmJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On .update() you have to specify the path for the key.

try the following:

```
let firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let uniqueID = "OEHCrSnKFrd87JDivvA0sLMnj8u1"
let updates = {};
updates["/status"] = false;
firebaseApp.database()ref("users/" + uniqueID).update(updates)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, Gabriel. It's working now.